# When did sentence acquire a negative connotation?

Tags: word-usage, etymology

***[Sentence](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sentence)***  in legal jargon refers, both as a noun an as a verb, to a punishment given by a judge in court to a person or organization after they have been found guilty.

Actually the original sense of sentence was neutral, more like verdict which could be either positive (not guilty) or negative(guilty)  for those involved

> [From early 14c.](https://www.etymonline.com/word/sentence) as "judgment rendered by God, or by one in authority; a verdict, decision in court.

When, an possibly why, did sentence start to be used only for negative legal judgements?

Comment: The Online Etymological Dictionary only mentions 'judgment' etc, which may be favourable. Whereas [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/sentence) has << Middle English (in the senses ‘way of thinking, opinion’, ‘court's declaration of punishment' >>. I think we need the OED here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth - Etymonline mentions “judgment, verdict and decision in court”, all of them are neutral.

Comment: Good question. It's interesting that Etymology Online doesn't address the question of when _sentence_in the sense of "punishment or penalty issued following an adverse verdict" originated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that "sentence" does have a negative connotation - although the convict might not agree.

The first entries in the OED for "Sentence(n.)" are

> †1. Way of thinking, opinion. Obsolete.
>
> 1340   Ayenbite (1866) 69   Þer byeþ zome..þet none guode techinge ne onderuongeþ ak alneway weryeþ hare sentense huet þet hit by.
>
> 1609   Bible (Douay) I. Josh. ix. 2   The Hetheite and Amorreite..were gathered, to fight against Iosue and Israel with one minde, and one sentence.

and

> 2. a. The opinion pronounced by a person on some particular question, usually, one on which he is consulted or which is being deliberated upon.
>
> c1386   G. Chaucer Melibeus ⁋366   I wolde fayn knowe how that ye vnderstonde thilke wordes and what is youre sentence.

From these we can see a link to and from decisions.

Sentence (n.) in the sense of a punishment, was originally an official decision made by the Church. To that extent it was also, technically, an opinion. It was not the punishment.

From OED

> 3. An authoritative decision; a judgement pronounced by a tribunal.
>
> †a. spec. = sentence of excommunication.
>
> c1290   S. Eng. Leg. 133/932   Ȝif ani man hond on ov set ich ov hote al-so Þat ȝe þe **sentence** of holi churche for swuche violence ȝe do, And holdez vp holi churche riȝte þat ov is bi-take.
>
> 1297   R. Gloucester's Chron. (Rolls) 10370   He esste boc & candle þe **sentence** to do bliue.

About a century later, it had expanded to

> b. gen. The judgement or decision of a court in any civil or criminal cause. Now rare in popular use; still technically applied to the decisions of the ecclesiastical and admiralty courts.
>
> c1386   G. Chaucer Doctor's Tale 172   The Iuge answerde: Of this in his absence I may nat yeue diffynytyue **sentence**.
>
> 1857   Act 20 & 21 Victoria c. 85 §16   A **Sentence** of Judicial Separation..may be obtained, either by the Husband or the Wife, on the ground of Adultery [etc.].

And around the same time or a little earlier it had reached its current meaning

> c. The judicial determination of the punishment to be inflicted on a convicted criminal. **Hence, the punishment to which a criminal is sentenced.**
>
> c1340   R. Rolle Prose Treat. 7   For-thy I had na stabyll purpos in gude, na perfite contrycyone, tharefore sentence of dampnacyone ffelle one me.
>
> 1598   W. Shakespeare Love's Labour's Lost i. i. 288   Sir I will pronounce your sentence: You shall fast a weeke with Branne and Water.
>
> 1893   C. G. Leland Memoirs I. 144   A noted murderer under sentence of death.

The word "sentence" in grammar was not recorded until:

> 1447   O. Bokenham Agnes in Lyvys Seyntys 682   Fro sentence to sentence, I dar wele seyn, I hym haue folwyde euen by & by.